# copy numbers following specific characters

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, grep

file1 contains:

```
SS1   2.979621e-01   3.022140e-02   4.273952e-05       0.107    0.223

Set   1:  err.est. 7.72199e-05  a 1  tau1 0.0816095  tau2 98.7691
```

I want to:

- copy the number following `SS1` in line1 `2.979621e-01` into a new `file2`
- next, to copy number following `err.est.` in line2 into a new `file3` and
- last copy the number following `tau1` in line2 into a new `file4`.

I know how to copy all characters following specific character such as:

```
grep "SS1" file1 | sed 's/*^. //' > file2
```

however that command copies the whole line

is there any way to say in the `sed` command to copy only certain number of characters?

Comment: if its position always fixed....use ```grep "SS1" file1 | awk '{print $2}'```

Comment: yes you are right!

Comment: @AkhilJ Why would anyone pipe ("normal", non-PCRE) `grep` output to `awk`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Illustrating the principle:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="SS1") print "1 ",$(i+1); '\
'if ($i=="err.est.") print "2 ",$(i+1); '\
'if ($i=="tau1") print "3 ",$(i+1); } }' inputfile

1  2.979621e-01
2  7.72199e-05
3  0.0816095
```

Writing to files instead:

```
awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="SS1") print $(i+1) >"file2"; '\
'if ($i=="err.est.") print $(i+1) >"file3"; '\
'if ($i=="tau1") print $(i+1) >"file4"; } }' inputfile
```

One output with three values:

```
$ awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="SS1") ss=$(i+1); '\
'if ($i=="err.est.") err=$(i+1); if ($i=="tau1") tau=$(i+1); } }; '\
'END { printf "%12s %16.9f %16.9f\n", ss,err,tau; }' inputfile

2.979621e-01      0.000077220      0.081609500
```

Comment: how about if i wanted this to be column wised in the same file such as: 2.979621e-01 7.72199e-05 0.0816095

Comment: @DimitrisMintis Simple. I have edited my answer.

Comment: super! you are a legend!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like:

```
awk '{for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^[[:alpha:]]/) f[$i] = $(i+1)}
     END {
       print f["SS1"]      > "file2"
       print f["err.est."] > "file3"
       print f["tau1"]     > "file4"
     }' < file1
```

With `sed`, you could do:

```
sed -n '
  h; /^\(.*[[:space:]]\)\{0,1\}SS1[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*$/ {
    s//\2/
    w file2
  }
  g; /^\(.*[[:space:]]\)\{0,1\}err\.est\.[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*$/ {
    s//\2/
    w file3
  }
  g; /^\(.*[[:space:]]\)\{0,1\}tau1[[:space:]]\{1,\}\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\).*$/ {
    s//\2/
    w file4
  }' < file1
```

Comment: is this possible with only regex... without awk?

Comment: @AkhilJ, well no, a regex is just a tool to match text, it cannot *write text to a file for instance*, you can have a regex as part of the solution (like this answer does), but the solution can't just be *a regex*.

Comment: @AkhilJ, I've added a `sed` solution.